# transform array to get united array?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry i am beginner in PHP. I have a problem with an array.

```
Array
(
    [Edisi] => 174|September|2001| 
)
Array
(
    [Pengantar] => Dear All.... 
)
Array
(
    [Tema] =>  Sami Mawon 
)
Array
(
    [Tema_isi] => **sesuatu!!!**
)
```

If i want to make to be like

```
Array
(
    [Edisi] => 174|September|2001|
    [Pengantar] => Dear All.... 
    [Tema] =>  Sami Mawon 
    [Tema_isi] => sesuatu!
)
```

How might I go about achieving it?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the manual page for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.